# Child process in php executes destructor of class objects created in parent process

Tags: php, fork, pcntl

In the below code. I am trying to understand the behavior.

```
class ForkManager 
{
    private $_max_workers = 3;
    private $_open_processes = 0;
    private $_tasks = array();

    public function setMaxWorkers($num)
    {
        $this->_max_workers = $num;
    }

    public function addTask($command)
    {
        $this->_tasks[] = $command;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        while($this->_tasks) {
            $command = array_shift($this->_tasks);
            $pid = pcntl_fork();
            if(!$pid) {
                /* Execute in child process start */
                echo "$command\n";
                exec($command, $return, $out);
                exit(0);
                /* Execute in child process end */
            } else {
                ++$this->_open_processes;
                //var_dump($this->_open_processes, $this->_max_workers);
                if($this->_open_processes >= $this->_max_workers) {
                    (pcntl_wait($status));
                    --$this->_open_processes;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function getOpenProcess()
    {
        return $this->_open_processes;
    }

    public function isAllTaskCompleted()
    {
        return $this->_open_processes;
    }
}


class Scheduler {

    public function __construct() {
        var_dump("Waking up...");
    }

    private function getTasksForCurrentHour() {
        //static for now
        return array(
            'startmusic',
            'logintohris',
            'checkforerrorsemail',
            'startcoffeemachine'
        );
    }

    public function run() {
        $fm = new ForkManager();
        $tasks = $this->getTasksForCurrentHour();
        foreach ($tasks as $key => $task) {
            $fm->addTask('php UnversalWorker.php ' . $task);
        }
        $fm->execute();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        var_dump("All tasks done... Going to sleep for an hour");
    }
}


$s = new Scheduler();
$s->run();
```

Now, the output of the code according to me should be

```
string(12) "Waking up..."
php UnversalWorker.php startmusic
php UnversalWorker.php logintohris
php UnversalWorker.php checkforerrorsemail
php UnversalWorker.php startcoffeemachine
string(44) "All tasks done... Going to sleep for an hour"
```

But the actual output is

```
string(12) "Waking up..."
php UnversalWorker.php startmusic
php UnversalWorker.php logintohris
php UnversalWorker.php checkforerrorsemail
string(44) "All tasks done... Going to sleep for an hour"
php UnversalWorker.php startcoffeemachine
string(44) "All tasks done... Going to sleep for an hour"
string(44) "All tasks done... Going to sleep for an hour"
string(44) "All tasks done... Going to sleep for an hour"
string(44) "All tasks done... Going to sleep for an hour"
```

It seems that every child process is calling the destructor of the parent process i.e. Scheduler class. I want to know is this the default behavior? If yes then any particular reason for that. And if no, then there must be some bug in my implementation. Can any one point me to that.

Comment: is there anything in `unversalWorker.php` that invokes the classes?

Comment: Nope. Infact if I replace it with `$fm->addTask('echo ' . $task);` still same result